# Downloading website files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a script to query files on an IIS website, then download those files automatically. So far, I have this:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.webclient
$source = "http://testsite:8005/"
$destination = "C:\users\administrator\desktop\testfolder\"
#The following line returns the links in the webpage
$testcode1 = $webclient.downloadstring($source) -split "<a\s+" | %{ [void]($_ -match "^href=['"]([^'">\s]*)"); $matches[1] }
foreach ($line in $test2) {
    $webclient.downloadfile($source + $line, $destination + $line)
}
```

I'm not that good at PowerShell yet, and I get some errors, but I manage to get a couple test files I threw into my wwwroot folder (the web.config file seems undownloadable, so I'd imagine thats one of my errors). When I tried to change my `$source` value to a subfolder on my site that had some test text files(example = `http://testsite:8005/subfolder/`, I get errors and no downloads at all. Running my `$testcode1` will give me the following links in my subfolder:
`/subfolder/test2/txt`
`/`
`/subfolder/test1.txt`
`/subfolder/test2.txt`
I don't know why it lists the test2 file twice. I figured my problem was that since it was returning the subfolder/file format, that I was getting errors because I was trying to download `$source + $line`, which would essentially be `http://testsite:8005/subfolder/subfolder/test1.txt`, but when I tried to remedy that by adding in a `$root` value that was the root directory of my site and do a `foreach($line in $testcode1) { $webclient.downloadfile($root + $line, $destination + $line) }`, I still get errors.
If some of you high speed gurus can help show me the error of my ways, I'd be grateful. I am looking to download all the files in each subfolder on my site, which I know would involve use of some recursive action, but again, I currently do not have the skill level myself to do that. Thank you in advance on helping me out!

Comment: this is a really well stated question, +1

Comment: Consider using wget for this task.

Comment: Additional details: I am using PowerShell 2.0, and cannot upgrade to v3 or use any cmdlets not native to PowerShell, nor install anything extra on my computers, therefore I am trying to get a solution I can perform with a standard Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Have you tried this other guy's method?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436694/how-to-download-a-whole-folder-of-files-subfolders-from-the-web-in-powershell

Comment: Yes, that method was used as the basis of what I am trying to do here, but when I typed up that one, it would not download anything. I uderstand what he is trying to do, but his method of splitting the source code to grab the links seems inefficient, yet without using his method, it is difficult for me to scavenge some of the useful code to better my own (lack of proficiency on my part, currently).

Answer (score 5):

This is to augment A_N's answer with two examples.

Download this Stackoverflow question to `C:/temp/question.htm`.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri stackoverflow.com/q/19572091/1108891 -OutFile C:/temp/question.htm
```

Download a simple text document to `C:/temp/rfc2616.txt`.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 -OutFile C:/temp/rfc2616.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to download files from a website is to use

`Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url`

Once you are able to get hold of the html  you can parse the content for the links.

`$result = (((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like “http*”} ) | select href).href`

Give it a try. Its simpler than $webclient = New-Object System.Net.webclient

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple Powershell script to clone an openbsd package repo. It probably would work / could be implemented in other ways/use cases for similar things.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/forgottentq/powershell/blob/master/Package_Repo_Cloner.ps1)

```
# Quick and dirty script to clone a package repo. Only tested against OpenBSD.
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$share = "\\172.16.10.99\wmfbshare\obsd_repo\"
$url = "https://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/amd64/"
cd $share
$packages = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing $url
$dlfolder = "\\172.16.10.99\wmfbshare\obsd_repo\"
foreach ($package in $packages.links.href){
    if ((get-item $package -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
        write-host "$package already downloaded"
    } else {
        write-host "Downlading $package"
        wget "$url/$package" -outfile "$dlfolder\$package"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.webclient
$source = "http://testsite:8005/"
$destination = "C:\users\administrator\desktop\testfolder\"
#The following line returns the links in the webpage
$testcode1 = $webclient.downloadstring($source) -split "<a\s+" | %{ [void]($_ -match  "^href=['"]([^'">\s]*)"); $matches[1] }
foreach ($line in $testcode1) {
    $Destination = "$destination\$line"
    #Create a new directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path $Destination)){
        New-Item $Destination -type directory -Force
    }
    $webclient.downloadfile($source + $line, $destination + $line)
}
```

I think your only issue here is that you were grabbing a new file from a new directory, and putting it into a folder that didn't exist yet (I could be mistaken).

You can do some additional troubleshooting if that doesn't fix your problem:

Copy each line individually into your powershell window and run them up to the foreach loop.  Then type out your variable holding all the gold:

```
    $testcode1
```

When you enter that into the console, it should spit out exactly what's in there.  Then you can do additional troubleshooting like this:

```
    "Attempting to copy $Source$line to $Destination$line"
```

And see if it looks the way it should all the way on down.  You might have to adjust my code a bit.

-Dale Harris

Comment: Your statement that my `$destination + $line` part was my issue was correct. After creating the subfolder in my test folder, the files downloaded, though I am still getting the following error message: 
`Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a webClient request"`
`At line:12 char:25`
`+    $webclient.downloadfile <<<< ($root + $line, $destination + $line)`
`    + CategoryInfo          :NotSpecified (:) [], MethodInvokationExeption` 
`    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodExeption`

Comment: I figure this error is because one of the lines returned as a link is to the parent directory, listed in my returned results as a \. How would I go about getting a statement in to ignore these?